# How to parse nested json without key's javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to parse nested json array without having any key, using JavaScript please help.

Json Data:

```
[
["S. No.", "Bank Name", "First 4 Letters of ", "IFSC", "Short Code", "Multimodal Code"],
["1", "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank", "ABHY", "ACB", "*99*87#"],
["2", "Allahabad Bank", "ALLA", "ALB", "*99*54#"],
["3", "Andhra Bank", "ANDB", "ANB", "*99*59#"],
["4", "Apna Sahakari Bank", "ASBL", "APN", "*99*85#"],
["5", "Axis Bank", "UTIB", "AXB", "*99*45#"],
["6", "Bank of Baroda", "BARB", "BOB", "*99*48#"],
["7", "Bank of India", "BKID", "BOI", "*99*47#"],
["8", "Bank of Maharashtra", "MAHB", "BOM", "*99*61#"],
["9", "Bhartiya Mahila Bank", "BMBL", "BMB", "*99*86#"],
["10", "Canara Bank", "CNRB", "CNB", "*99*46#"],
["11", "Central Bank of India", "CBIN", "CBI", "*99*51#"],
["12", "Corporation Bank", "CORP", "CRB", "*99*57#"],
["13", "DCB Bank", "DCBL", "DCB", "*99*65#"],
["14", "Dena Bank", "BKDN", "DNB", "*99*78#"],
["15", "Federal Bank", "FDRL", "FBL", "*99*72#"],
["16", "Gujarat State Co-op Bank", "GSCB", "GSC", "*99*90#"],
["17", "Hasti Co-op Bank", "HCBL", "HCB", "*99*89#"],
["18", "HDFC Bank", "HDFC", "HDF", "*99*43#"],
["19", "ICICI Bank", "ICICI", "ICI", "*99*44#"],
["20", "IDBI Bank", "IBKL", "IDB", "*99*49#"],
["21", "Indian Bank", "IDIB", "INB", "*99*58#"],
["22", "Indian Overseas Bank", "IOBA", "IOB", "*99*52#"],
["23", "IndusInd Bank", "INDB", "IIB", "*99*69#"],
["24", "ING Vysya Bank", "VYSA", "ING", "NA"],
["25", "Janata Sahakari Bank", "JSBP", "JSB", "*99*81#"]
]
```

This is json format. I want to get bank names like "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank", "Allahabad Bank" , but don't parse first array that is :

```
["S. No.", "Bank Name", "First 4 Letters of ", "IFSC", "Short Code", "Multimodal Code"],
```

Please help.

Comment: If the first row is the mappings for the rows values you could use it to map your data into an array of objects then you can access them by name. `data[0].bankName` Ive created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbouwmwr/1/) as an example. So long as the mappings array index's match all will be dandy

Comment: @SunnyDhiman since many of the answers below helped you, it would be nice if you choose any one of them as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So bank name is always second element in array.

```
// skip first line as it's header.
for (var i = 1; i < banksArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(banksArray[i][1]); // "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a `array` of `arrays` and you need to loop through the main array (neglect the index 0 as you dont need it) and inside the loop access only the first index values, since this has the bank names

```js
var data = [
["S. No.", "Bank Name", "First 4 Letters of ", "IFSC", "Short Code", "Multimodal Code"],
["1", "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank", "ABHY", "ACB", "*99*87#"],
["2", "Allahabad Bank", "ALLA", "ALB", "*99*54#"],
["3", "Andhra Bank", "ANDB", "ANB", "*99*59#"],
["4", "Apna Sahakari Bank", "ASBL", "APN", "*99*85#"],
["5", "Axis Bank", "UTIB", "AXB", "*99*45#"],
["6", "Bank of Baroda", "BARB", "BOB", "*99*48#"],
["7", "Bank of India", "BKID", "BOI", "*99*47#"],
["8", "Bank of Maharashtra", "MAHB", "BOM", "*99*61#"],
["9", "Bhartiya Mahila Bank", "BMBL", "BMB", "*99*86#"],
["10", "Canara Bank", "CNRB", "CNB", "*99*46#"],
["11", "Central Bank of India", "CBIN", "CBI", "*99*51#"],
["12", "Corporation Bank", "CORP", "CRB", "*99*57#"],
["13", "DCB Bank", "DCBL", "DCB", "*99*65#"],
["14", "Dena Bank", "BKDN", "DNB", "*99*78#"],
["15", "Federal Bank", "FDRL", "FBL", "*99*72#"],
["16", "Gujarat State Co-op Bank", "GSCB", "GSC", "*99*90#"],
["17", "Hasti Co-op Bank", "HCBL", "HCB", "*99*89#"],
["18", "HDFC Bank", "HDFC", "HDF", "*99*43#"],
["19", "ICICI Bank", "ICICI", "ICI", "*99*44#"],
["20", "IDBI Bank", "IBKL", "IDB", "*99*49#"],
["21", "Indian Bank", "IDIB", "INB", "*99*58#"],
["22", "Indian Overseas Bank", "IOBA", "IOB", "*99*52#"],
["23", "IndusInd Bank", "INDB", "IIB", "*99*69#"],
["24", "ING Vysya Bank", "VYSA", "ING", "NA"],
["25", "Janata Sahakari Bank", "JSBP", "JSB", "*99*81#"]
];


for(var i=1; i< data.length; i++){  //neglect 0 index
   console.log(data[i][1]);         //access the first index, as it has the bank name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this JSON in a string, then use JSON.parse to get the array first

```
var arr = JSON.parse( str ); //convert to array object if input is a string
var bankNames = arr.map(function(val){ return val[1] }); //get only bankname second index of each row
bankNames.splice(0,1); //remove first row result
```

if the input is already an array then ignore first statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your `getBanks()` function .

```js
var bdata = [
["S. No.", "Bank Name", "First 4 Letters of ", "IFSC", "Short Code", "Multimodal Code"],
["1", "Abhyudaya Co-op Bank", "ABHY", "ACB", "*99*87#"],
["2", "Allahabad Bank", "ALLA", "ALB", "*99*54#"],
["3", "Andhra Bank", "ANDB", "ANB", "*99*59#"],
["4", "Apna Sahakari Bank", "ASBL", "APN", "*99*85#"],
["5", "Axis Bank", "UTIB", "AXB", "*99*45#"],
["6", "Bank of Baroda", "BARB", "BOB", "*99*48#"],
["7", "Bank of India", "BKID", "BOI", "*99*47#"],
["8", "Bank of Maharashtra", "MAHB", "BOM", "*99*61#"],
["9", "Bhartiya Mahila Bank", "BMBL", "BMB", "*99*86#"],
["10", "Canara Bank", "CNRB", "CNB", "*99*46#"],
["11", "Central Bank of India", "CBIN", "CBI", "*99*51#"],
["12", "Corporation Bank", "CORP", "CRB", "*99*57#"],
["13", "DCB Bank", "DCBL", "DCB", "*99*65#"],
["14", "Dena Bank", "BKDN", "DNB", "*99*78#"],
["15", "Federal Bank", "FDRL", "FBL", "*99*72#"],
["16", "Gujarat State Co-op Bank", "GSCB", "GSC", "*99*90#"],
["17", "Hasti Co-op Bank", "HCBL", "HCB", "*99*89#"],
["18", "HDFC Bank", "HDFC", "HDF", "*99*43#"],
["19", "ICICI Bank", "ICICI", "ICI", "*99*44#"],
["20", "IDBI Bank", "IBKL", "IDB", "*99*49#"],
["21", "Indian Bank", "IDIB", "INB", "*99*58#"],
["22", "Indian Overseas Bank", "IOBA", "IOB", "*99*52#"],
["23", "IndusInd Bank", "INDB", "IIB", "*99*69#"],
["24", "ING Vysya Bank", "VYSA", "ING", "NA"],
["25", "Janata Sahakari Bank", "JSBP", "JSB", "*99*81#"]
];

var getBanks = (b, t = b.shift()) => b.map(e => e[1]);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(getBanks(bdata), null,2) + "</pre>");
```